# About upstart and systemd

Tags: gunicorn

My system is ubutnu 16.04,so I need to transform upstart into systemd,all I need to do is add /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service ??

my upstart is

```
 start on net-device-up 
 stop on shutdown

 respawn 

 setuid yangxg 
 chdir /home/yangxg/sites/demo.zmrenwu.com/blogproject

 exec ../env/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/demo.zmrenwu.com.socket blogproject.wsgi:application
```

How can I transform it into systemd

```
[Unit]
Description=My script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/my-script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm not clear about these parameters...I am new in learning gunicorn...